# RoR, where do I put generally used templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I know that for each controller you have a specific views folder that holds all of it's views. I also know there is the layout folder for the layouts.
But what if I have a bit of a template that keeps popping up in many templates across the system but it's not a footer or header or otherwise layout related.
I want to refer to it using the <%= render.... %> command but where should I put this template?
Is there a generally agreed upon location?
Can I just create a directory under views and store it there?

Comment: `views/shared` is pretty good

Answer (score 2):

Rails will automatically look in 'views/application' and in the folder that contains the current parent view.

That said, you can place partials anywhere you like, and refer to them like so:

```
<%= render 'foo/bar' %>
```

As @apneadiving suggests, 'shared' is a good name for the folder.

```
<%= render 'shared/bar' %>
```